# PonyORM: using WITH RECURSIVE CTE clause without writing raw SQL (recursive query)

Tags: common-table-expression, recursive-query, ponyorm, recursive-cte

Is it possible to write a query in PonyORM's syntax that will be translated into a SQL query with a WITH RECURSIVE CTE clause? If yes, how?

I know I can write raw SQL queries with select_by_sql() and select(), but I specifically want to know if I must use raw SQL or if I can use PonyORM's pythonic syntax, for writing recursive queries.